# Kobold2d - Orientation

Tags: iphone, ios, orientation, kobold2d

Im created a game in cocos2d, because i wanted to use some UIKit elements i found kobold2d.

I ported the game, but the problem is that my iPhone stimulator is rotated,

but not the node that is shows.

Do is have to use:

```
background.rotation = 270;
```

For every sprite that i create or did i overlooked a method

i'm using Kobold2D v2.0.3 in combination with xCode 4.5.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In KKAppDelegate.m, change this line:

```
// set the Navigation Controller as the root view controller
[window addSubview:navController.view];
```

to this:

```
// set the Navigation Controller as the root view controller
window.rootViewController = navController;
```

I'll release an updated version soon.

Comment: I cant access the KKAppDelegate.m, only the .h file. My AppDelegate doesnt have such a method

Answer (score 0):

You will have to enable the Autorotation in lua file in your resources ..!

Comment: The scenes i developed are for landscape. So it should view the scenes as landscaped. It should not autorotate

Comment: In your lua file, the device orientation might be set to portrait mode, Just have look over the setting in lua file in the resources folder of your project.